# How to set circled enumerate with different colours connected with lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate, tcolorbox, enumitem

my target is to obtain enumerate as shown below.

[image]

I adapted some codes below.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*\mycirc[1]{\tikz[baseline=(myc.base)]{\node[shape=circle,fill=green!75!black,inner sep=2.2pt](myc){#1};}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\mycirc{\bfseries \arabic*}]
\item You decide to use the normal distribution to approximate the binomial distribution. You want to know the probability of getting exactly 16 tails out of 20 coin flips.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*}]
\item
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\item 108 people took a test for which the probability of passing is 0.88. Let \textit{X} be the number of people who passed the test. Using the normal distribution .... 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which resulted into the image shown below.

[image]

Additional image as requested in the comments by @yannisl
[image]

Comment: In your target image you have two different colours, and 1 is connected to 2, but 2 is not connected to 3, leading to different looking endpoints of the lines. How would you want to specify that in the list (It doesn't look like it could be very automatic).

Comment: @AlanMunn the line connecting the items is the main target actually but I appreciate the colors as well

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question though. The connection between 1 and 2 is different than the connection between 2 and 3 even though they are all items in the same list. How would this be determined in practice?

Comment: @AlanMunn let's focus on 1 and 2 only because I have realized that the initial target can be achieved manually

Comment: How many questions are likely to be present? I also think you should possibly post and additional image if you have, i.e., if it is from a book to understand why 2 and 3 are different ; @AlanMunn 's question is very valid and saying ignore it, is not helping. People are likely to put serious effort and time to help you so detailing the question a bit better is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: fig~1]

I propose a solution based on `tcolorbox`; the `enumerate` environment is modified into `lenumerate` which takes two arguments: the color and the distance from the text left margin to the vertical segment of the enumeration.

**Remark.** I maintained the initial code of the questioner.

**Update.** I modified the code such that it works in case the enumeration splits on two pages.  I haven't verified what happens if it splits on three pages.  Probably it won't work, but using something like `overlay middle` should do...

**The code**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}
\tcbset{shield externalize}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\mycirc[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(myc.base)] {%
    \node[shape=circle, fill=#2, inner sep=2.2pt] (myc) {#1};
  }
}

\newenvironment{noticeB}[2]{%  color, delta x
  \tcolorbox[%
  notitle,
  empty,
  enhanced,  % delete the edge of the bottom page for a broken box
  breakable,
  coltext=black,
  opacityback=0,
  fontupper=\rmfamily,
  parbox=false,
  noparskip,
  boxrule=-1pt,  % width of the box' edges
  frame hidden,
  left=0\parindent,  % inner space from text to the left edge
  right=0\parindent,
  top=-1pt,
  bottom=5pt,
  % boxsep=0pt,
  before skip=2ex,
  after skip=2ex,
  overlay unbroken and first={%
    \draw[color=#1, fill=#1, line width=1pt]
    ($(frame.north west) +(#2, -15pt)$)
    -- ($(frame.south west) +(#2, 7pt)$);
  },
  overlay unbroken={%
    \draw[color=#1, fill=#1, line width=1pt]
    ($(frame.north west) +(#2, -15pt)$)
    -- ($(frame.south west) +(#2, 7pt)$) circle (1.5pt);
  },
  overlay last={%
    \draw[color=#1, fill=#1, line width=1pt]
    ($(frame.north west) +(#2, -1pt)$)
    -- ($(frame.south west) +(#2, 7pt)$) circle (1.5pt);
  }]
}{\endtcolorbox}

\newenvironment{lenumerate}[2]{%
  \begin{noticeB}{#1}{#2}%
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\mycirc{\bfseries \arabic*}{#1}]}{%
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{noticeB}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{lenumerate}{green!65!black}{11pt}
\item
  You decide to use the normal distribution to approximate the
  binomial distribution. You want to know the probability of getting
  exactly 16 tails out of 20 coin flips. 
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*.}]
  \item
    Some text.
  \item
    Some mode text.
  \item
    Well\ldots
  \end{enumerate}
\item
  108 people took a test for which the probability of passing is
  0.88. Let \textit{X} be the number of people who passed the
  test. Using the normal distribution\ldots
\end{lenumerate}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest `tcolorbox` too. It's a much better choice for this sort of formatting.

Comment: @Daniel N much respect. Is there any work around that can enable the line connecting the items to break to the next page because apparently it's not

Comment: Hi @Uncle C ! modified the answer accordingly---for a two pages enumeration but not for three, though.

Comment: @DanielN  This is a very good solution. It also works nicely with \ref and \label putting the reference in a numbered circle. You might considr using `\labelformat` to make the circles smaller for this label.

Comment: Many thanks @yannisl !  Feel free to modify it!  Anyway, the disks are not mine; I used Uncle C 's code.